# Is there any type of distribution which has zero-mean, unit-variance; but, is non-Gaussian?

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-process

The standard normal (Gaussian) distribution has zero-mean and unit-variance.

I wonder whether there is a zero-mean, unit-variance, and non-normal (non-Gaussian) distribution or not?

Comment: @Sullysaurus, it depends on the random variable's distribution. For instance, what happens if you try to do this to Cauchy variable?

Comment: Unlimited number of them, e.g. continous uniform from $-(\sqrt 12) /2$ to  $(\sqrt 12) /2$ ...

Comment: @Aksakal Yeah, that's a good point. I'm way off base here.

Comment: Search our site for [standardize](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=standardize): this is a procedure that will turn *any* distribution with finite second moment into one with zero mean and unit variance.

Comment: You can scale the laplace or the logistic distributions to unit variance and the moments will be matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably infinite number of distributions in [location-scale family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location-scale_family), e.g. Student t (location scale). You can convert many distributions into zero mean and unit variance by using [this technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location-scale_family#Converting_a_single_distribution_to_a_location-scale_family).

Comment: Are you really trying to imply the fourth moment of any Gaussian distribution is zero?  If not, then please elaborate on what you mean by "only two first moments equal to 0 and 1."

Comment: @whuber, that's Fri morning mistake, long week.